# How to Process multiple Images through Opencv in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have multiple images in a folder which i want to process and apply some opencv functions to them.

I am trying to find contours of every image present in the folder.
I am able to process one at a time.

**Code for single image**

```
img = cv2.imread('abc.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,85,155,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

thresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh,(11,11),0)

_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

final = cv2.drawContours(img,contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

cv2.imshow('Output', final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What i want is to apply these operations on multiple images present in the folder.

Comment: Use a for loop. and `os.listdir` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a for loop and loop over that directory and apply this procedure to every image in the directory:

```
for image in os.listdir('path_ti_images_folder'):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join('path_to_images_folder', image))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,85,155,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    thresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh,(11,11),0)

    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    final = cv2.drawContours(img,contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

    cv2.imshow('Output', final)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: thanks for `os`  i also saved the files in another folder,Thanks.

Comment: It could also be a good practice to make this into a function and call it when needed.

Comment: great,will do that